# можно ли кросскомпилировать один и тот же С++ код под Windows, macOS и Linux?

Tags: c++, кроссплатформенность

Меня интересует процесс кроссплатформенной разработки, когда одно и то же приложение разрабатывается сразу для нескольких ОС. Например:

1) Windows
2) MacOS
3) Linux

Можно ли используя только C++, написать программу и просто откомпилировать ее под разные ОС, например при помощи Visual Studio?

Или нужно каждый раз, писать отдельный код, уже на других языках программирования и использовать для каждой ОС свой родной компилятор?

Comment: Консольные программы, не использующие платформоспецифические библиотеки, проблем с переносом на другую систему обычно не имеют. (По модулю разного размера типов данных.)

Comment: Возможно для кого-то вопрос покажется глупым, но я дальше Windows никогда не вылезал. Поэтому просьба поделиться насколько трудоемким является перенос кода с одной платформы на другую или все таки у виртуальной машины Java нет достойной альтернативы?

Comment: @VladD спасибо за комментарий, но речь о полноценных приложениях с GUI

Comment: Все дело в библиотеках. Если вы используете напрямую WinAPI, то у вас возникнут большие проблемы на других платформах. Вообще ответ состоит из двух букв "Qt" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы имеете в виду -- "компилируем один раз, а потом используем полученный загрузочный модуль в разных ОС"? Если  так, то мне такие системы не известны. В каждой ОС надо заново собирать из исходников. А вот писать переносимый исходный код (с некоторыми ограничениями) вполне возможно.

Comment: @Michael: Смотрите, вот у вас есть код, который показывает нотификацию в system tray под Windows. Как вы его спортируете под десктопный линукс? Там нету такого понятия как system tray вовсе. Или, например, меню — под Windows вы можете показывать его хоть посередине окна, а под MacOS его принято его показывать в отдельной от приложения части экрана, а под телефоны вообще его нет.

Comment: @avp "Я правильно понял, что вы имеете в виду -- "компилируем один раз, а потом используем полученный загрузочный модуль в разных ОС"?  - нет, не так. Пишем один раз, а потом компилируем под каждую ОС.

Comment: @VladID Если front end писать на Qt, а back end с помощью стандартной библиотеки С++, а потом компилировать под Linux c помощью GCC разве это не будет решением?

Comment: @Michael, если пересобирать, то в принципе нет проблем, `#if`/`#elif`/`#endif`  и вперед

Comment: @avp: `#if WINDOWS <первая программа> #elif LINUX <вторая программа> #elif MAC <третья программа> #endif`!

Comment: В компании которой я работал (они писали программы для музыкальной индустрии) писали программу отдельно под каждую ОС. Такой способ очень затратный, но зато можно избежать много проблем перед выпуском новой версии.

Comment: @VladD, ага, в либах, реализующих абстракции